# Regarding Test Class in Salesforces

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

How to Write a test Class for Wrapper Class or Dto Class,how to call Wrapper Class in Test Class Please anyone Provide with Sample Example

Comment: If you have already done it for a controller, there's no much difference. Can you post your code and tell us where you struggling?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create object of inner or wrapper class by this way:

```
ViewRelatedController.PageSection page = new ViewRelatedController.PageSection();
```

pagesection here is inner class

Note: Your inner class must be public for this.

reference: [How to include inner class/wrapper class in test method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31595/how-to-include-inner-class-wrapper-class-in-test-method)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and best way i think  is call the method in which you are populating the wrapper...